# JSON web Tokens and cookie authentication in the same time

Tags: json, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I have a web app with cookie and JWT authentication. The site uses cookie schema, web api - JWT schema. And there is a controller, which requires both types(if request has 'Bearer' header - JWT, otherwise - cookie, but only the cookie one works. Here are ConfigureServices and Configure methods:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddCommonLogger();
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddDatabase(Configuration);
        services.AddLogicUnits();
        services.AddFrontendLogic(Configuration);
        services.ConfigureSettings(Configuration);
        services.AddCommonServices();

        var authTokenSettings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenProviderSettings)).Get<TokenProviderSettings>();
        services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, u =>
                {
                    u.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = authTokenSettings.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = authTokenSettings.Audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authTokenSettings.Key))
                    };
                })
                .AddCookie("CookieAuthScheme", cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UnhandledExceptionLoggerProvider provider)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(provider);
        app.AddNLogWeb();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

If I set AuthenticationScremes like this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,CookieAuthScheme")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyRecords()
    { // Do some work...}
```

I get http 404, and if I use empty `[Authorise]` attribute a cookie authentication is used.

If I remove `.AddCookie("CookieAuthScheme", cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true);` the JWT-based authentication is used and works fine. What am I doing wrong?